# how to publish my extension on joomla extension directory?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I wrote a component for Joomla!.I Read http://docs.joomla.org/Publishing_to_JED .
but i can't find submit button or link on http://extensions.joomla.org for submit the extension.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you must create an account on the Joomla Extensions Directory (and log in).
- Then, find the category that you think the extension should belong to (for example "Fake Registered Users" would belong to the "Fake Data" category)
- On this page you will see a button saying "submit extension" (as long as you are logged in)
- Follow the instructions and once submitted, it will usually take about 3 weeks, depending on the amount of other extensions submitted, to be approved.

Answer (score 1):

I only found tow URLs about your questions!

http://docs.joomla.org/Publishing_to_JED
and
http://extensions.joomla.org/component/content/article/15